# sql - Generate a unique random value for each row

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm making an SQL table that stores data for `students`. For a column called `roll_number`, I want to generate a random number between two values, say 4000 and 5000 and assign it to the column for each row while making sure that the value has not been used before as roll number has to be unique.

Can anyone give me the query I can use for setting this up? I'm relatively new to SQL.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand

Comment: SELECT FLOOR(4000+ (RAND() *(5000-4000+1))); will give you 4000 -> 5000 inclusive range  - up to you to check before insert if already used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select x.*, @i := @i + 1 randid from my_table, (Select @i:=4000) vars order by rand();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create and check random number is already exist or not .

```
/// Get the unique roll_number
SELECT FLOOR(4000 + RAND() * 1000) AS roll_number
FROM student
WHERE roll_number NOT IN (SELECT roll_number FROM table)
LIMIT 1

UPDATE student set roll_number = ? WHERE student_id = ?
```

Comment: that will give range 4000 -> 9000! Otherwise I'd have marked it as correct. See my comment under question....